# Initialize a blank form when using [(ngModel)] in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, object, initialization

I'm learning Angular2 from the official guide. I have created a CRUD application, and everything is working perfectly fine as far the the functionality goes. One thing that I would like to have is the ability to use [(ngModel)] and still have blank form fields on initial loading of the form. Currently for ngModel to work, I have the form initialized with hard-coded values for the model. Here's my setup:

**The Component:**

```
@Component({
    selector:'create-form',
    templateUrl: './app/createTemplate.html'
})
export class CreateComponent{   
    model = new DemoBean(123321, 1,'test',1.3);     //TODO - initialize blank form fields for these values.
    http:Http;

    constructor(http:Http){             //Dependency injection of Http.
        this.http = http;
    }
    msg:string;

    onSubmit(id: number, str: string, num: number, d: number) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.model = new DemoBean(id,num,str,d);
        this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/create', JSON.stringify(this.model),{headers:headers}).map((res) => res.text())
            .subscribe(msg => this.msg = msg);
    }

}
```

**Form template :**

```
<div class="container">
    <form (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(id.value, str.value, num.value, d.value)" #demoForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="long_id">long Id</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.id" #id required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="string_str">String str</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.str" #str required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="int_num">int num</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.num" #num required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="double_d">double d</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.d" #d required>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!demoForm.form.valid">Submit</button>

        <div><p>{{msg}}</p></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: What do you mean by "blank form fields for these values." - they can only be either blank or a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an empty value

```
model = new DemoBean('', '','','');
```

Comment: That's the problem. The form fields show these values on initial-load. Is it possible to initialize the model and not show the values in the form? Like the way forms naturally are, blank to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted the code a bit. So why don't you just provide an empty model (like shown in my updated answer)?

Comment: I had to use a combination of **null** and **''**, but it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach and fine

**my model:**

```
export class model {
    constructor(
            public id: number,
            public title: string,
            public description: string
      ) { }
      static readonly EMPTY_MODEL = {
           id: 0,
           title: '',
           description: ''
        };
}
```

**initialize blank:**

```
mdl: model = model.EMPTY_MODEL;
```

***and no need to `new()` expression.***